# write data to text file in azure data factory version 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

It's seem ADF v2 does not support writing data to TEXT file (.TXT).

1. After select File System

   [image: FileSystem]
2. But don't see TextFormat at the next screen

   [image: TextFormat]

So do we any method to write data to TEXT file ?

Thanks,
Thai

Comment: What type of the data you want to write is? In my opinion, the `CSV`/`JSON` format also are text format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Factory only support these 6 file formats:
[image]

Please see: [Supported file formats and compression codecs in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs).

If we want to write data to a txt file, the only format we can using is Delimited text, when the pipeline finished, you will get a txt file.

Reference: [Delimited text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text): Follow this article when you want to parse the delimited text files or write the data into delimited text format.

For example, I create a pipeline to copy data from Azure SQL to Blob, choose DelimitedText format as Sink dataset:
[image]

The txt file I get in Blob Storeage:

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is DelimitedText dataset. You can specify extension as part of the file name